# Compiled Android 4.2.2 AOSP, error when flashing

Tags: android, binary

I compiled the build with no build errors at all. Went to flash my source built ROM and I get this "error executing the updater binary."

This is the error from the "recovery.log"

```
line 4 col 37: syntax error, unexpected STRING, expecting $end
1 parse errors
E:Error executing updater binary in zip '/external_sd/Flash This/full_xt926.bdh.signed.zip'
Error flashing zip '/external_sd/Flash This/full_xt926.bdh.signed.zip'
```

I looked in the updater script and didn't notice any errors at all. Here's a copy of that.

```
show_progress(0.500000, 0);
format("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system");
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system", "/system"); "0 /system/
package_extract_file("check_data_app", "/tmp/check_data_app");
set_perm(0, 0, 0777, "/tmp/check_data_app");
run_program("/tmp/check_data_app");
package_extract_dir("data", "/data");
set_perm_recursive(1000, 1000, 0771, 0644, "/data/app");
package_extract_dir("system", "/system");
symlink("/persist/WCNSS_qcom_wlan_nv.bin", "/system/etc/firmware/wlan/prima/WCNSS_qcom_wlan_nv.bin");
symlink("/system/lib/libwiperjni_v02.so", "/system/lib/libwiperjni.so");
symlink("/system/lib/libxt_v02.so", "/system/lib/libxt_native.so");
symlink("Roboto-Bold.ttf", "/system/fonts/DroidSans-Bold.ttf");
symlink("Roboto-Regular.ttf", "/system/fonts/DroidSans.ttf");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/[");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/[[");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/adjtimex");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/arp");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/ash");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/awk");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/base64");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/basename");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/bbconfig");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/blkid");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/blockdev");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/brctl");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/bunzip2");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/bzcat");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/bzip2");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/cal");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/cat");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/catv");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/chattr");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/chgrp");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/chmod");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/chown");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/chroot");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/clear");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/cmp");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/comm");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/cp");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/cpio");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/crond");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/crontab");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/cut");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/date");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/dc");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/dd");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/depmod");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/devmem");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/df");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/diff");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/dirname");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/dmesg");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/dnsd");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/dos2unix");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/du");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/echo");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/ed");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/egrep");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/env");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/expand");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/expr");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/false");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/fbsplash");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/fdisk");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/fgrep");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/find");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/flash_lock");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/flash_unlock");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/flashcp");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/flock");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/fold");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/free");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/freeramdisk");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/fstrim");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/fsync");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/ftpget");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/ftpput");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/fuser");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/getopt");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/grep");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/groups");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/gunzip");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/gzip");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/halt");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/head");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/hexdump");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/id");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/ifconfig");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/inetd");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/insmod");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/install");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/ionice");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/iostat");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/ip");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/kill");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/killall");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/killall5");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/less");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/ln");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/losetup");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/ls");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/lsattr");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/lsmod");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/lsusb");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/lzcat");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/lzma");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/lzop");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/lzopcat");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/man");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/md5sum");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/mesg");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/mkdir");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/mke2fs");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/mkfifo");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/mkfs.ext2");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/mkfs.vfat");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/mknod");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/mkswap");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/mktemp");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/modinfo");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/modprobe");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/more");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/mount");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/mountpoint");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/mpstat");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/mv");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/nanddump");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/nandwrite");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/nbd-client");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/netstat");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/nice");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/nohup");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/nslookup");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/ntpd");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/od");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/patch");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/pgrep");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/pidof");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/ping");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/pipe_progress");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/pkill");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/pmap");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/poweroff");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/printenv");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/printf");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/ps");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/pstree");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/pwd");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/pwdx");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/rdev");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/readlink");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/realpath");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/renice");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/reset");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/resize");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/rev");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/rm");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/rmdir");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/rmmod");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/route");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/run-parts");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/rx");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/sed");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/seq");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/setconsole");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/setserial");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/setsid");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/sh");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/sha1sum");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/sha256sum");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/sha3sum");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/sha512sum");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/sleep");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/sort");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/split");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/stat");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/strings");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/stty");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/sum");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/swapoff");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/swapon");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/sync");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/sysctl");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/tac");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/tail");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/tar");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/taskset");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/tee");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/telnet");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/telnetd");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/test");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/tftp");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/tftpd");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/time");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/timeout");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/top");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/touch");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/tr");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/traceroute");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/true");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/ttysize");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/tune2fs");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/umount");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/uname");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/uncompress");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/unexpand");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/uniq");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/unix2dos");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/unlzma");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/unlzop");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/unxz");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/unzip");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/uptime");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/usleep");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/uudecode");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/uuencode");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/vi");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/watch");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/wc");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/wget");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/which");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/whoami");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/xargs");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/xz");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/xzcat");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/yes");
symlink("busybox", "/system/xbin/zcat");
symlink("mksh", "/system/bin/sh");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/cat");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/chmod");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/chown");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/cmp");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/cp");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/date");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/dd");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/df");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/dmesg");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/du");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/getevent");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/getprop");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/grep");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/hd");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/id");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/ifconfig");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/iftop");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/insmod");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/ioctl");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/ionice");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/kill");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/ln");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/log");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/ls");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/lsmod");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/lsof");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/md5");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/mkdir");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/mount");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/mv");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/nandread");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/netstat");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/newfs_msdos");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/notify");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/printenv");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/ps");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/r");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/reboot");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/renice");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/restart");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/rm");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/rmdir");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/rmmod");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/route");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/schedtop");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/sendevent");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/setconsole");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/setprop");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/sleep");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/smd");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/start");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/stop");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/sync");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/top");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/touch");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/umount");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/uptime");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/vmstat");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/watchprops");
symlink("toolbox", "/system/bin/wipe");
symlink("wiperiface_v02", "/system/bin/wiperiface");
set_perm_recursive(0, 0, 0755, 0644, "/system");
set_perm_recursive(0, 0, 0777, 0777, "/system/etc/init.d");
set_perm_recursive(0, 2000, 0755, 0755, "/system/bin");
set_perm(0, 1000, 0750, "/system/bin/iptables");
set_perm(0, 3003, 02750, "/system/bin/netcfg");
set_perm(0, 3004, 02755, "/system/bin/ping");
set_perm(0, 2000, 06750, "/system/bin/run-as");
set_perm(0, 1000, 0750, "/system/bin/tc");
set_perm(1002, 1002, 0440, "/system/etc/dbus.conf");
set_perm(1014, 2000, 0550, "/system/etc/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks");
set_perm(0, 2000, 0550, "/system/etc/init.goldfish.sh");
set_perm_recursive(0, 0, 0755, 0555, "/system/etc/ppp");
set_perm(0, 2000, 0755, "/system/vendor");
set_perm(0, 2000, 0755, "/system/vendor/lib");
set_perm_recursive(0, 2000, 0755, 0644, "/system/vendor/lib/drm");
set_perm(0, 0, 0644, "/system/vendor/lib/drm/libdrmwvmplugin.so");
set_perm_recursive(0, 2000, 0755, 0755, "/system/xbin");
set_perm(0, 0, 06755, "/system/xbin/su");
symlink("/system/xbin/su", "/system/bin/su");
set_perm(0, 0, 06755, "/system/xbin/librank");
set_perm(0, 0, 06755, "/system/xbin/procmem");
set_perm(0, 0, 06755, "/system/xbin/procrank");
set_perm(0, 0, 06755, "/system/xbin/tcpdump");
show_progress(0.200000, 0);
show_progress(0.200000, 10);
package_extract_file("boot.img", "/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/boot");
show_progress(0.100000, 0);
assert(package_extract_file("boot.img", "/tmp/boot.img"),
       write_raw_image("/tmp/boot.img", "boot"),
       delete("/tmp/boot.img"));
unmount("/system");
unmount("/data");
```

Comment: Just FYI, there's not a lot of traffic on StackOverflow around actually compiling Android itself. You might also try somewhere like XDA or RootzWiki.

Comment: thanks, i'll try xda as well

Answer (score 0):

In your third line you have:

```
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system", "/system"); "0 /system/
```

Do you really intend to put that `"0 /system/` there at the end? Removing it seems like it might fix your problem.

Comment: That is just how the updater-script came out after compiling. Will remove that.